# Possible to get last modified date of folder?

Tags: vb.net

I have a block of code which reads all the files in a directory, and gets the latest date from all those files. Not sure if I'm being silly, but is there a way to do the same thing but by getting the last modified date of the folders within that directory instead of the files?

```
Dim chkPath = "C:\CheckFolders"
Dim directory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(chkPath)
Dim File As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()
Dim File1 As System.IO.FileInfo
Dim LastModified As String

For Each File1 In File
    LastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(chkPath & "\" & File1.Name).ToShortDateString()
Next

MsgBox(LastModified)
```

Comment: A [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) object has a `LastWriteTime` property.

Comment: Or you could use the [Directory.GetLastWriteTime(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetLastWriteTime_System_String_) like you used `File.GetLastWriteTime`.

Comment: And you should use `file1.FullName` instead of `chkPath & "\" & File1.Name`, and if you *really* want to use the latter, `Path.Combine(chkPath, file1.Name)` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hoping that the directory entries are returned in ascending date order, you should actively find the latest one. You can do that with the LINQ [Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8) method like this:

```
Shared Function GetLatestFileModified(d As String) As DateTime

    Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(d)
    Dim latest = di.EnumerateFiles().Max(Function(i) i.LastWriteTimeUtc)

    Return latest

End Function

Shared Function GetLatestDirectoryModified(d As String) As DateTime

    Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(d)
    Dim latest = di.EnumerateDirectories().Max(Function(i) i.LastWriteTimeUtc)

    Return latest

End Function
```

For example,

```
Dim src = "C:\temp"
Console.WriteLine(GetLatestFileModified(src).ToShortDateString())
Console.WriteLine(GetLatestDirectoryModified(src).ToShortDateString())
```

might give

> 26/04/2019
>   10/04/2019

Comment: Thanks very much Andrew. I managed to work it out after a painful hour but your method is a lot better. I'll research into LINQ now!

Comment: @S.T You're welcome :) One thing to remember with file I/O is that exceptions could occur at any time, e.g. the user might manage to delete the files while it's trying to use them, so some sort of graceful error handling is a good idea once you've got the basics working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in my solution.

```
        'Check if file needs updating
        Dim infoStkReader As System.IO.DirectoryInfo
        infoStkReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo(SUI)
        Dim CurrentdirectoryDate As DateTime = infoStkReader.LastWriteTime
```

Where SUI is the directory path.

Thanks,
Richard.